# Image Intervention InvalidImageDataStringException Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Morning People, I cant seem to fix an error, I currently pass base64 string to my [image intervention api](https://github.com/Intervention/image) and try and save it to a public directory.

**Error**

> error:
>   {type:Intervention\Image\Exception\InvalidImageDataStringException,
>   message:,…} file:
>   "/home/celeb/public_html/dev/vendor/intervention/image/src/Intervention/Image/Image.php"
>   line: 1968 message: "" type:
>   "Intervention\Image\Exception\InvalidImageDataStringException"

The data string I pass to Image::make -> http://pastebin.com/BGbUeZhr

**Code**

```
public function upload(){

    $fileName = Input::get('name');
    $explode    = explode('.',$fileName);
    $extension  = strtolower(end($explode));

    $img = Image::make(base64_decode(Input::get('data')));

    $fileName = "profiles/".md5(time()).'.'.$extension;
    $path = public_path($fileName);

    if($img->save($path)){
        echo "Image Added";
    }
}
```

**Without the base64_decode error.**

```
{error:{type:Intervention\Image\Exception\ImageNotFoundException,…}}
error: {type:Intervention\Image\Exception\ImageNotFoundException,…}
file: "/home/celeb/public_html/dev/vendor/intervention/image/src/Intervention/Image/Image.php"
line: 198
message: "Image file (data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA8AAAAIcCAYAAAA5Xcd7AAAgAElEQVR4Xuydh0MUWRLG30RyRgEJKmDOYYN39//f7a5uNOtG3eQqihInXn31uprHiCIyzEzPfG+vrloYpru/Hob5daVUVZbjogJUoCkKPH/+3N27dy+2x48fuxcvXsS2tLTk6vErmkqlnUtlHHxKvPzjrfOtVsuyr7Jz6itN0YM7pQJUgApQgYNVIJPpddnckMvmh9Wns/0uncrK34acS6XhszscgP+bkUrBp+Rv..
```

Comment: I don't think you need to use `base64_decode` do you?

Comment: No, it's not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not decode the string, a base64 encoded string of the image is needed for Image Intervention to make the image. Look [here](http://image.intervention.io/api/make) for the source parameter.

Parameters are;

Source to create an image from. The method responds to the following input types:

- string - Path of the image in filesystem.
- string - `URL` of an image (allow_url_fopen must be enabled).
- string - `Binary` image data.
- string - `Data-URL` encoded image data.
- string - `Base64` encoded image data.
- resource - PHP resource of type `gd`. (when using GD driver)
- object - `Imagick` instance (when using Imagick driver)
- object - `Intervention\Image\Image` instance
- object - `SplFileInfo` instance (To handle Laravel file uploads via `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile`)

EDIT:

`data:image/png;base64,` should not be there;

Use;

```
$image_str = Input::get('data');
$array = explode(',', $image_str);

Image::make($array[1]);
```

Comment: @Brent updated answer. BTW commas will not appear within a base64 encoded string so dont worry about it splitting less than it should.

Comment: Hi Matt, I have updated the code, but I get the following error.  http://codetidy.com/5867/

Comment: @Brent Are you using the latest version?

Comment: my composer has has (*), , so shouldn't that be the latest? "intervention/image": " * "

Comment: @Brent * is a wildcard for any thing. I would restrict it to version 2.* instead as base64 strings will not work on 2.0.8 and below.

Comment: Or you can try `Image::make(base64_decode($array[1]))`.

Comment: Oh I fixed it, just added  "intervention/image": "2.0.14" .. cant believe after all that ha. Thanks for time mate